# Unit Tests name convention for grouping tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, naming-conventions, junit5

I read some articles about tests naming conventions and decided to use one with "should". It works pretty nice in most cases like:

- shouldAccessDeniedIfWrongPassword
- shouldReturnFizzBuzzIfDiv3And5
- shouldIncreaseAccountWhenDeposit

But I encountered problems while testing DecimalRepresentation class which displays numbers in diffrent numeral systems, just look at code:

```
public class DecimalRepresentationTest {

    private DecimalRepresentation decimal;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        decimal = new DecimalRepresentation();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturnZeroIfNumberNotSpecified() {
        assertEquals("0", decimal.toBinary());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturn10IfNumber2() {
        decimal.setNumber(2);
        assertEquals("10", decimal.toBinary());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturn1111IfNumber15() {
        decimal.setNumber(15);
        assertEquals("1111", decimal.toBinary());
    }
}
```

Now it's not bad, but in case I'm testing negative inputs it looks terrible:

```
    @Test
    void shouldReturn11111111111111111111111110001000IfNumberNegative120() {
        decimal.setNumber(-120);
        assertEquals("11111111111111111111111110001000", decimal.toBinary());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturn11111111111111111111111111111111IfNumberNegative1() {
        decimal.setNumber(-1);
        assertEquals("11111111111111111111111111111111", decimal.toBinary());
    }
```

In examples above I'm testing twice for positive and negative input to be sure there is no hardcoded result and algorithm works fine so i decided to group tests in nested classes for keeping convention:

```
@Nested
@DisplayName("Tests for positive numbers")
class PositiveConverter {
    @Test
    void shouldReturn10IfNumber2() {
        decimal.setNumber(2);
        assertEquals("10", decimal.toBinary());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturn1111IfNumber15() {
        decimal.setNumber(15);
        assertEquals("1111", decimal.toBinary());

    }
}

@Nested
@DisplayName("Tests for negative numbers")
class NegativeConverter {
    @Test
    void shouldReturn11111111111111111111111110001000IfNumberNegative120() {
        decimal.setNumber(-120);
        assertEquals("11111111111111111111111110001000", decimal.toBinary());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturn11111111111111111111111111111111IfNumberNegative1() {
        decimal.setNumber(-1);
        assertEquals("11111111111111111111111111111111", decimal.toBinary());
    }
}
```

I realize it's overcomplicated because of convention. In case I make lapse it could look much better:

```
@Test
void testPositiveConversions() {
    assertAll(
            () -> {decimal.setNumber(2); assertEquals("10", decimal.toBinary());},
            () -> {decimal.setNumber(15); assertEquals("1111", decimal.toBinary());}
    );
}

@Test
void testNegativeConversions() {
    assertAll(
            () -> {decimal.setNumber(-120); assertEquals("11111111111111111111111110001000", decimal.toBinary());},
            () -> {decimal.setNumber(-1); assertEquals("11111111111111111111111111111111", decimal.toBinary());}
    );
}
```

Should i break convention to keep it simple? The same naming problem i have with tests they get Lists with input and outputs or dynamic tests:

```
@TestFactory
Stream<DynamicTest> shouldReturnGoodResultsForPositiveNumbers(){ // look at method name lol
    List<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 15));
    List<String> outputs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("10", "1111"));

    return inputs.stream().map(number -> DynamicTest.dynamicTest("Test positive " + number, () -> {
        int idx = inputs.indexOf(number);
        decimal.setNumber(inputs.get(idx));
        assertEquals(outputs.get(idx), decimal.toBinary());
    }));
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't name the test cases for the exact result. All you're doing is duplicating the implementation of the test case. Call it `shouldReturnExpectedValueForMinusOne`, or whatever.

Comment: So in case with multiple assertions shouldReturnExpectedValuesForNegativeNumbers is fine?

Comment: Sure. I mean, saying "should do the expected thing" is a bit redundant, because by definition, tests test that it's doing what you expect; but it's better than saying "the thing I expect it to do is XXX, and I expect it to do XXX", which is what you're doing by putting the result in the name.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much :)

Comment: I know, opinionated, but upvoted just to show my appreciation for you spending time to think about such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Names are supposed to be helpful. Sometimes rules help finding good names, sometimes, they do not. And then the answer is to drop the rule, and maybe go for something completely different, like:

```
@Test
void testResultForNegativeInput() {
  decimal.setNumber(-120);
  assertEquals("11111111111111111111111110001000", decimal.toBinary());
 }
```

And if you have several of these methods, maybe adding "ForMinus120" or so would be acceptable.

But instead of spending energy naming here: the real issue is that you are using the wrong kind of testing: you have a whole bunch of **input** data, that simply result in different output values to check. All your tests are about: one special input value should lead to a special output value.

You don't do that with many almost similar test methods - instead you turn to [parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests)! Meaning: use a table to drive your test. For JUnit**5** and parameterized tests turn [here](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) (thanks to user [Sam Brannen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388980/sam-brannen)).

It is great that you spend time and energy to make your tests easy to read. But in this case, that leads to a lot of code duplication. Instead, put down the input/output values into a *table*, and have **one** test to check all entries in that table.

Comment: Does it mean Object[0][0] is input and Object[0][1] expected value? And so on
Object[1][0] input, Object[1][1] expected etc?

Comment: The table contains the data that you need for each test. So, yes - a table row would contain -120 and the corresponding expected string value.

Comment: Okay so parameterized tests was what i was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: FYI: the OP asked about JUnit 5 (i.e., JUnit Jupiter). Thus, the link to parameterized test support should point here for [Parameterized Tests](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests).

Comment: @minizibi This is a different topic then. Please consider asking a **new** question. Keep in mind. this is a question answer site. One question, one/more answers. One topic. New issue, new question. So please change your edits, and turn them into a new question (it is always fine to link to the original one to provide context). And feel free to drop me a comment as soon as you got there.

Comment: Okay i deleted edited part and it looks like i found an answer, configuration hell part 1289124 : P thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

i've modeled mine after [Roy Osherove's](http://www.osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html) method, here's the regex

`^(setup|teardown|([A-Z]{1}[0-9a-z]+)+_([A-Z0-9]+[0-9a-z]+)+_([A-Z0-9]+[0-9a-z]+)+)$`